# Select bit in std_logic_vector based on unsigned with multiplication

Tags: vhdl, std-logic-vector

Is the following allowed in VHDL(2008)?

```
CONSTANT FLAG := 2;
signal flags : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal link_nr : unsigned(3 downto 0);

flags(2*to_integer(link_nr)+1)  <= data(FLAG); --happens in a process
```

While it does synthesize it results in very odd and unexpected behavior where random bits in the vector are overwritten. The problem seems to mainly exist when `link_nr` is set `0`.
`link_nr` is guaranteed to never be bigger than `7`.
To be honest, it seems odd and I wouldn't know how exactly you would build this construct in logic, but if it's not allowed, I'd expect the compiler to catch it and at least throw a warning at me.

Comment: It's very hard to help debug this without seeing the `process` that contains the assignment.

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to have you debug it, I'm just asking is it generally allowed to do this sort of assignment (where you have an unsigned signal with some other arithmetic manipulations in the selection) allowed.

Comment: Apparently it is allowed, in the sense that your synthesizer accepts it, else you would have errors in synthesis. So please [edit] your question and provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example, with emphasis on "complete."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be allowed.

How it gets implemented in logic, is probably that there's first some logic to generate `2*link_nr+1`. That signal then works as the select signal for a multiplexer, which in turn drives the enable signals for the registers/latch - or whereever the `flags` is stored. Then only the desired bit gets updated with `data(FLAG)`.

By the way, *link_nr is not guaranteed to never be bigger than 7*: if link_nr := "1111", then it's 15. And 2*15+1 = 31, so you could be accessing `flags(31)`. This is most likely causing the "very odd and unexpected behaviour". Synthesis tool probably will be happy with this, but you should get an error for violating the vector bounds in simulation.